# Cygwin command line installer - option for UNIX/DOS line endings?

Tags: cygwin

When installing cygwin from command line, is there a command line option to choose between UNIX and DOS line endings?

```
setup-x86_64.exe --quiet-mode --site http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin ?
```

Comment: Where would you expect that selection to take effect? When calling Cygwin programs?

Answer (score 0):

the option was removed long ago.

UNIX default, Line Feed, is used